# nginx variables (cname) in proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

i am trying dynamically set a the proxy_pass destination where the variable would be the cname of the original request.

what i have right now is:

```
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name (.*).domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://$1.otherdomain.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $1.otherdomain.com;
```

but unfortunately this ends up in a 502 bad gateway. 
nothing really works when using a variable in `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set_header`.

i also tried to use `(?<cname>.+)` or `(?P<cname>.+)` in the server name and `$cname` as the variable.

what is wrong and why does it end up in a 502?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use regex in server name, you need to prepend the name with a tilde "~"

```
server_name ~(.*).domain.com;
```

[**UPDATE**]
Tried it and it successfully set the value in $1. But still get 502 and my nginx error log shows

```
no resolver defined to resolve xyz.otherdomain.com
```

even though I point that name to my localhost in my /etc/hosts file.

Find this [article](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) that explains this issue well. Basically in this special case (variable in upstream domain name), you need to use the ["resolver" directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#resolver) to point to a dns server (e.g., 8.8.8.8 from google dns server) that can resolve this dynamic domain name.

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

It works in my test with a public upstream domain name. If you upstream domain names are local, you need to set up a local dns server for them.

Comment: Note: if you hard code the domain name in the proxy_pass directive, it's all fine. No need for a dns resolver. In that case, I guess nginx finds those names' ip addresses when it parses the config file.

Comment: Do **NOT** use a publicly accessible DNS server such as `8.8.8.8`. [To prevent DNS spoofing, it is recommended configuring DNS servers in a properly secured trusted local network.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)

Answer (score 0):

The server name for proxy_pass using variables, will be a special situation.

```
proxy_pass       http://$1.otherdomain.com;
```

> In this case, the server name is searched among the described [server groups](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), and, if not found, is determined using a resolver.

If you do not like to use resolver. You can use below like hosts file.

```
upstream www1.otherdomain.com { server 10.x.x.1; } 
upstream www2.otherdomain.com { server 10.x.x.2; }
```